# using sqllite for sharing data

Tags: android, arrays

I'm writing a quiz app and I would like to access my arrays anywhere in the code, I tried with SharedPreferences but it didnt worked. Does anybody know how to put an array of arrays:

```
public static final int[] ALL_ANSWERS = {
    R.array.answer,
    R.array.answer1,
    R.array.answer2,
    R.array.answer3
    };
```

in database and access them anywhere in the code. These answers are XML string arrays and I would like to put them as the button text, apropos, as the answers to the question. Every string array is the batch of answers to a batch of questions. Example of an answers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<new_answers>
<answer1>
    <text1>Zvonimir</text1>
    <text2>Tomislav</text2>
    <text3>Branimir</text3>
    <text4>Viseslav</text4>
</answer1>
<answer2>
    <text1>Stipe Mesic</text1>
    <text2>Ivo Josipovic</text2>
    <text3>Franjo Tuđman</text3>
    <text4>Mate Granic</text4>
</answer2>
<answer3>
    <text1>Hrvatski politicar</text1>
    <text2>Hrvatski akademik</text2>
    <text3>Hrvatski glazbenik</text3>
    <text4>Hrvatski branitelj</text4>
</answer3>
</new_answers>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It could work if you defined your string-array correctly (actually they're not defined correctly). Android using exact conventions how to create resources and you should follow them.

Try to define your arrays in the same way like this one:

```
<string-array name="answer1">
    <item>Zvonimir</item>
    <item>Tomislav</item>
    <item>Branimir</item>
    <item>Viseslav</item>
</string-array>
```

Finally place them to values folder as **arrays.xml**. And now it should works.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just store each answer as a single tuple with the attributes being answerId - choice1 - choice2 - choice3 - choice4?

It looks like each answer has the same number of choices so rather than an array you could just just set your schema up this way. Access the row associated with the question number and retrieve the choices. You could even add a column for which answer is correct if you didn't want to create a new relation (though I'm not sure this is the best design - I.e. 3rd normal form?)

It seems to me just having separate tables for questions and answers and using well designed queries is easier than trying to store and parse XML arrays.